# Random number in AutoIt is not working

Tags: random, numbers, autoit

The intention of this string is to generate a random number in this format: l = letter n = num,

```
LLNNN
```

Instead, it gives me this:

```
NN
```

Or sometimes:

```
N
```

#### Code

```
Local $destination = "C:\Users\Ryan\Pictures\Aurora.jpg"

If Random() < 1 Then
    $Lettera = Chr(Random(Asc("A"), Asc("Z")))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Letterb = Chr(Random(Asc("A"), Asc("Z")))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numbera = Chr(Random(48, 57, 1))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numberb = Chr(Random(48, 57, 1))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numberc = Chr(Random(48, 57, 1))
Endif

SplashImageOn("Splash", $destination, 312, 146, 450, 300, 1)
Sleep(9000)
SplashOff()
If MsgBox(1, "code generator", "Create a new key?") = 1 Then
    msgBox(0, "code generator", "Your registry is:" + $Lettera + $Letterb + $Numbera + $Numberb + $Numberc)
EndIf
```

Comment: If your random number code is broken and you receive a number the first time is that number random? Zzzap mind blown.....On the other hand is it trying to add the numbers since you are using a + instead of a & while appending values?

Comment: Just to mention: The idea behind a splash screen is to already display something while some (mostly time intensive) initialisation tasks have to be done. So that the user can watch something while the program is actually not yet fully loaded. Not to just display an image for 9 seconds while doing nothing... That's more a waste of time ;-) So you could use `SplashImageOn(...)` before your Random-initialisation and probably remove the `Sleep(...)` statement...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign everything as a string value and then append it all at the end.

```
Local $destination = "C:\Users\Ryan\Pictures\Aurora.jpg"

If Random() < 1 Then
    $Lettera = Chr(Random(Asc("A"), Asc("Z")))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Letterb = Chr(Random(Asc("A"), Asc("Z")))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numbera = Chr(Random("48", "57", "1"))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numberb = Chr(Random("48", "57", "1"))
Endif
If Random() < 1 Then
    $Numberc = Chr(Random("48", "57", "1"))
Endif

SplashImageOn("Splash", $destination, 312, 146, 450, 300, 1)
Sleep(9000)
SplashOff()
If MsgBox(1, "code generator", "Create a new key?") = 1 Then
    msgBox(0, "code generator", "Your registry is:" & $Lettera & $Letterb & $Numbera & $Numberb & $Numberc)
EndIf
```